# Cramer's rule and the Padé approximant

Tags: approximation-theory, pade-approximation

Padé approximants are a particular type of rational approximation. The $L, M$ Padé approximant is denoted by

$$[L/M] = P_L(x)/Q_M(x)$$

where $P_L(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $L$, and  $Q_M(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $M$. The formal power series

$$f(x) = \sum _{j=0}^\infty f_jx^j,$$

determines the coefficients by the equation

$$f(x) -P_L(x)/Q_M(x)=O(x^{L+M+1}).$$

There is also an extra condition added by Baker which states that

$$Q_M(0)= 1.$$

A proof at the beginning of Essentials of Padé approximants shows that the $[L/M]$ Padé approximant is unique when it exists (Frobenius, $1881$).

Now, it is also well known that Jacobi made a breakthrough in $1846$. In particular, he applied Cramer's rule to get a determinant solution to the Padé approximant equations.

For $P_L(x)$ and $Q_M(x)$, a simplification of Cauchy's solution to the problem of rational interpolation produces two determinant solution formulas:

The numerator, $P_L(x)$, can be represented by

$$\label{ten}
P_L(x)=\mathrm{det}\,\begin{vmatrix} f_{L-M+1} & f_{L-M+2} & \cdots & f_{L+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\f_L & f_{L+1} & \cdots &f_{L+M} \\ \sum_{j=M}^L f_{j-M}x^j & \sum_{j=M-1}^L f_{j-M+1}x^j & \cdots & \sum_{j=0}^L f_jx^j \end{vmatrix}\ $$

Similarly, the denominator can be represented by

$$\label{nine}
Q_M(x)=\mathrm{det}\,\begin{vmatrix} f_{L-M+1} & f_{L-M+2} & \cdots & f_{L+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\f_L & f_{L+1} & \cdots &f_{L+M} \\ x^M & x^{M-1} & \cdots & 1 \end{vmatrix}\ $$

However, it isn't clear to me how Jacobi found these determinant solutions. If I go and review the source:

> Jacobi, C. G. J. $(1846)$ Uber die Darstellung einer Reihe Gegebner Werthe durch eine Gebrochne Rationale Function. J. Reine Angew. Math. (Crelle) $30, 127-156.$

I find that [Crelle's journal](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1846.issue-30/issue-files/crll.1846.issue-30.xml) contains the necessary information on pages $127-156$ of the $1846$ issue. However, the paper is in German and I cannot read it.

Does anyone know if this paper has been translated into English? Is there some way I could find this out on my own? I am looking to do the derivation myself and wasn't able to find an equivalent article in English.

Comment: [Baker](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Vkk4JNLKbLoC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=cramer%27s+rule+Pad%C3%A9+approximant&source=bl&ots=kTVjKwUtNY&sig=KRFsuOvYYnJG49pGvQModJe-OTI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijlY2I2_DcAhVol1QKHdMxAGIQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cramer's%20rule%20Pad%C3%A9%20approximant&f=false) pp. 4-7 discusses this.

Comment: Yes, Baker states that Jacobi found the relationship from the rational interpolation formulation given by Cauchy in a lecture in the 1820s. Baker doesn't show how Jacobi derived it.

Comment: You could try a [reference request on HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add the expression of $Q_{n,m}$, $Q_{n,m}(z)=b_{0}+b_{1}z+\dots+b_{m}z^{m}$, as a new equation in the original system, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
f_{n+1}b_{0}&+&f_{n}b_{1}&+&\cdots&+&f_{n-m+1}b_{m}&=&0 \\ 
\vdots&&\vdots &&&&\vdots &\;\;\;\;\;&\vdots\\ 
f_{n+m}b_{0}&+&f_{n+m-1}b_{m-1}&+&\cdots&+&f_{n}b_{m}&=&0\\ 
b_{0}&+&b_{1}z&+&\cdots&+&b_{m}z^{m}&=&Q_{n,m}(z),
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
considering the $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{a}
    \Delta_{m}(z)=\begin{vmatrix}
f_{n+1}&f_{n}    &\cdots &f_{n-m+1}\\ 
\vdots &\vdots   & &\vdots \\ 
f_{n+m}&f_{n+m-1}&\cdots&f_{n}\\ 
1      & z       &\cdots & z^{m} 
\end{vmatrix}\neq0,
\end{equation}
by obtaining the expression of $ b_{0}$ using the Cramer rule, we conclude
$$b_{0}=(-1)^{m}Q_{n,m}(z)\frac{H_{n,m}}{\begin{vmatrix}
f_{n+1}&f_{n}&\cdots&f_{n-m+1} \\ 
\vdots&\vdots&  &\vdots \\ 
f_{n+m}&f_{n+m-1} &\cdots &f_{n}\\ 
1&z&\dots&z^{m} 
\end{vmatrix}},$$
for $z$ that verify the formula of $P_{n,m}$. Therefore, we have shown that is true for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Delta_{m}(z)\neq0 $. It follows that is true $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ since $Q_{n, m}(z)$ and $\frac{(-1)^{m}b_{0}}{H{n,m}}\Delta_{m}(z)$ are polynomials at the most $m$ degree and it is enough that they coincide in $m+1$ points so that both polynomials are equal.